# Нахождение минимального элемента при помощи рекурсивной функции в одномерном массиве

Tags: c

Прошу пояснить что делает функция `minimal`(построчно) и для чего мы выполняем то или иное действие в функции `minimal`. В частности, я не понимаю что делает `k=size>>1`, `array+k` и `size-k`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
     
int minimal (int *array, int size)
{
    int l, r, k;
     
    if (size==1) 
        return *array;
     
    l = minimal(array, k=size>>1);
    r = minimal(array+k, size-k);
     
    return l < r ? l : r; 
}
     
void main(void) 
{
    int i;
    int a[10];
     
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        printf("Vvedite znachenie elemnte %d massiva a: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    printf ("Minimalnoe znachenie massiva = %d", minimal(a,10));
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Где вы такие извращения находите? `k=size>>1` -- размер пополам; `array+k` -- адрес правой половины; `size-k` -- размер правой половины. Идея в том, что делим массив пополам и ищем минимум в каждой из его половинок. Потом выбираем минимум из них.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Опираясь на комментарий [@avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp), распишу немного подробнее.

Во-первых, соглашусь с комментатором, что это то ещё извращение.

Во-вторых, по непонятному:

1. `k=size>>1`: здесь используется оператор побитового сдвига `>>`. Он сдвигает двоичное представление числа вправо на столько бит, сколько стоит после `>>`. В данном случае на 1. То есть, если, например, `size` в двоичном виде был `1000100110001011`, то станет `0100010011000101` (сдвинулось вправо на 1, самый правый элемент пропал, слева добавился 0). В данном случае это сделано для простого деления на 2 с округлением в меньшую сторону. То есть, эквивалентной записью было бы `k = floor(size / 2)`. Но сдвигом это работает быстрее (процессору так проще).
2. `array+k` наращивает указатель на массив на `k`. Теперь, при рекурсивном вызове функции, `array` будет начинаться не с нулевого элемента, а с `k`-ого. Это аналогично передаче указателя на `k`-ый элемент массива вот так: `&array[k]`.
3. `size - k` – здесь всё просто. На предыдущей строке `k` присваивается половина размера массива с округлением в меньшую сторону, а значит оставшаяся часть массива, те самые `size - k` элементов идут в следующий рекурсивный вызов.
4. Назначение функции – найти наименьший элемент массива с помощью дробления его на половинки, тех половинок на ещё половинки и так далее, пока половинки не станут размером в 1 элемент. Потом выбирается, какая из половинок больше, и возвращается в результат.
5. Бонусом расскажу, что значит запись `l < r ? l : r`. Вдруг это тоже не понятно. Это аналогично простому условию `if`. Всё, что до знака `?` – условие. Между вопросом и `:` – действие, если условие выполнено. Всё, что после `:` – если не выполнено. То есть в данном случае это можно переписать как:

```c
if (l < r)
    return l;
else
    return r;
```

P.S. Я пояснил только непонятные моменты. Если Вам непонятно абсолютно всё, Вам не сюда, а в учебники по C.